# How to get and array inside an array with variable array 'name' on React?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm setting an API to get the Cart::content() and trying to access via Fetch from React, i get it right but i don't know how to get the data since the array name of every product in cart is a random md5. Let me explain it better.

I just did a simple Fetch from the url to get this Json content which are the item in cart identifiers and attributes:

```
{
  "a775bac9cff7dec2b984e023b95206aa": {
    "rowId": "a775bac9cff7dec2b984e023b95206aa",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Auto 2",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 397739,
    "options": [

    ],
    "tax": "83525.19",
    "isSaved": false,
    "subtotal": "397739.00"
  },
  "564dd0ab34b63878ca2237c47a620cf2": {
    "rowId": "564dd0ab34b63878ca2237c47a620cf2",
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Auto 21",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 370070,
    "options": [

    ],
    "tax": "77714.70",
    "isSaved": false,
    "subtotal": "370070.00"
  }
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/cart')
        .then((res)=>res.json())
        .then((data)=>{
          this.setState({
            items: data,
          })
        });

  }
```

if i do:

```
 this.setState({
            items: data.a775bac9cff7dec2b984e023b95206aa.name,
          })
```

I will get the first object name but that (a775bac9cff7dec2b984e023b95206aa) is a variable name so How can i access the attribute inside the object inside another object indiferent the object name?. It's a bit diffcult to explain but hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: In PHP you probably return an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-59) these don't exist in JS/JSON so it'll be converted to Object, I suggest not using an associative array as JSON api endpoint but just use [indexed arrays without keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-60)

Comment: So the items on the state is just the value of a name? not an array?

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = {
  "a775bac9cff7dec2b984e023b95206aa": {
    "rowId": "a775bac9cff7dec2b984e023b95206aa",
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Auto 2",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 397739,
    "options": [

    ],
    "tax": "83525.19",
    "isSaved": false,
    "subtotal": "397739.00"
  },
  "564dd0ab34b63878ca2237c47a620cf2": {
    "rowId": "564dd0ab34b63878ca2237c47a620cf2",
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Auto 21",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 370070,
    "options": [

    ],
    "tax": "77714.70",
    "isSaved": false,
    "subtotal": "370070.00"
  }
}

const dataKeys = Object.keys(data)
console.log(dataKeys)

const newData = dataKeys.map( eachId =>{
    return data[eachId]
})
console.log(newData)
```

Pass the `newData` to the `child Component` so that it will be able to loop over this map and display the name of each product.

hoping i have got the question right.

Comment: Why all the temporary values and removing the key? You could have done: `this.setState({items: Object.entries(data)=>([key,value])=>({...value,key})`